# Change login page for spring security plugin in grails

Tags: spring, grails, spring-security, grails-plugin, grails-2.2

Is there a way that I can create my own custom login page and send the data to login controller of spring security plugin. I currently see my code redirecting directly to the default login page of spring security plugin.

Answer (score 27):

The 2.0 plugin comes with its own auth.gsp page, so if you create your own (either modify the plugin's or create your own) and put it in grails-app/views/login/auth.gsp it will be used. In 1.2.x the auth.gsp is in your app source, so edit it there.

If you want to further customize the login process, I did a talk at http://burtbeckwith.com/blog/?p=1090 and there's some sample code that adds a 3rd login parameter. That code is based on the 1.2.x plugin and would need to be updated for 2.0, but the ideas are the same.

Comment: Hello Burt, If I just create a gsp named auth.gsp and place it in the folder grails-app/views/login/auth.gsp, would it override the default auth.gsp or do I need to create another login controller that extends the login controller provided by the plugin.

Comment: You only need to do this for auth.gsp, but you can do both or either - application classes and GSPs always override those from plugins.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

I copied the file auth.gsp from here:

https://github.com/grails-plugins/grails-spring-security-core/blob/master/grails-app/views/login/auth.gsp

to grails-app/views/login/auth.gsp