# Where is spring security default login page code located?

Tags: java, spring-security

Where is the default login page generated in *Spring Security 4* when you use the simplest of configurations?

```
<http>
...
    <form-login/>
</http>
```

I am using this [basic sample web application for Spring Security](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/tree/master/samples/tutorial-xml).

Is almost the same as this question [Where is the default login page for the spring security core plugin?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32130327/2692914) but for Java.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

It is generated from this class `org.springframework.security.web.authentication.ui.DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter` :

```
private String generateLoginPageHtml(HttpServletRequest request, boolean loginError, boolean logoutSuccess) {
    String errorMsg = "none";

    [...]

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    sb.append("<html><head><title>Login Page</title></head>");

    if (formLoginEnabled) {
        sb.append("<body onload='document.f.").append(usernameParameter).append(".focus();'>\n");
    }

    [...]
```

Answer (score 4):

[`DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/master/web/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/ui/DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter.java) will be used to generate default forms in the case where a user doesn't configure a login page. It has a private `generateLoginPageHtml` responsible for generating the default html view.